# Does AroundReplace work with Quantity?

Tags: bugs, units, around

When I try to use `AroundReplace` with units it issues `Around::compat` message and outputs something strange:

```
(* $Version === "12.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)" *)

In[1] := AroundReplace[x, {x -> Quantity[Around[1.0, 0.1], "Meters"]}]

Around::compat: Meters and DimensionlessUnit are not compatible units.
Out[1] = Around[Quantity[Around[1., 0.1], "Meters"], 0]
```

Is this reproducible? A bug in an `AroundReplace` implementation or am I doing something wrong? Can I patch `` Language`UncertaintyDump`iAroundReplace `` or something?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions. *Do* add this tag to other people's posts if the bug has been confirmed. See the tag description for more details.

Comment: McSaks's code also gives an error in 12.0.

But the following works OK: `AroundReplace[Quantity[x, "Meters"], {x -> Around[1.0, 0.1]}]` and woudl achieve the desired end.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is a bug. `Around` is explicitly documented to work with `Quantity`, per its doc page.